# Passing an Arraylist<String> from Activtiy to Fragment android

Tags: android, arraylist, nullpointerexception, fragment, bundle

I am in the process of adding `Tabs` in my Application. So I want to move my custom `RecyclerView`'s adapter `Arraylist` from `MainActivity` to `Tab1_Fragment`. I don't use custom `Models`, it's just a basic `ArrayList<String>`. I created a `method` to send the `ArrayList` via a `Bundle`. Below the code:

*MainActivity.java*

*sendData:*

```
private void sendData() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putStringArrayList("KEY", namelist);
        Tab2_fragment myFragment = new Tab2_fragment();
        myFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.container, myFragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
        Log.d(TAG, "sendData: Data packed!");
}
```

Then the packed ArrayList has to be recieved. I have done this by calling `getArguments().getStringArrayList("KEY");`

Here the code:

```
ArrayList<String> namelist = getArguments().getStringArrayList("KEY");
```

But then I get a classic NPE. But wait, wait I already have googled on StackOverFlow for the same problem, but without success.

Here the Log:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.basiciptv, PID: 7868
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.ArrayList android.os.Bundle.getStringArrayList(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.basiciptv.Tab2_fragment.onActivityCreated(Tab2_fragment.java:48)
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2717)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.activityCreated(FragmentStateManager.java:336)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1186)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1354)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveFragmentToExpectedState(FragmentManager.java:1432)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1495)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.executeOps(BackStackRecord.java:447)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOps(FragmentManager.java:2167)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1990)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1945)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execSingleAction(FragmentManager.java:1816)
        at androidx.fragment.app.BackStackRecord.commitNowAllowingStateLoss(BackStackRecord.java:303)
        at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:238)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1244)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1092)
        at androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1622)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24549)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.internalMeasureChildren(ConstraintLayout.java:1227)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onMeasure(ConstraintLayout.java:1572)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24549)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:143)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24549)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24549)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24549)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1552)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:842)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:721)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24549)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:6828)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onMeasure(DecorView.java:742)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:24549)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:3007)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1834)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2123)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1722)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:7605)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1029)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:852)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:787)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:1014)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7403)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

More information:

> Creating Tabs

*MainActivity.java*

```
tabLayout = findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tab1 = findViewById(R.id.Tab1);
        tab2 = findViewById(R.id.Tab2);
        viewPager = findViewById(R.id.container);

        pageAdapter = new PageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());

                if (tab.getPosition() == 0){
                    pageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }

                if (tab.getPosition() == 1){
                    pageAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });


        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
```

*PageAdapter.java*

```
import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;

public class PageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private int numoftabs;

    public PageAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm, int numoftabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.numoftabs = numoftabs;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new Tab1_fragment();
            case 1:
                return new Tab2_fragment();
            default:
                return null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return numoftabs;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(@NonNull Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated!!

Comment: Your `PageAdapter` doesn't set any arguments on the fragments it creates in `getItem()` and that's the one that is crashing. How exactly are the fragments in your `PageAdapter` related to the one you *are* setting arguments on?

Comment: I don't think that the fragments are related at all. Well, I don't really know.. I just followed this tutorial from Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B7ohofe-Nk8